# ionic IOS allow access to youtube

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework

How can I get my Ionic App to allow access to YouTube?

I did not want to add:

```
  <allow-intent href="*"/>
```

But adding:

```
allow-intent href="https://www.youtube.com/*"/>
```

Has no effect, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Did you take care of App Transport Security? Since iOS9 per default any request is blocked. You have to either explicitly whitelist a specific host or disable the feature completely.

Have a look at [Apple's description right here](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CocoaKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009251-SW33).

Add the configuration to the info.plist of your Xcode project.

Whitelist a specific server:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

Disable ATS completely (not recommended by Apple and might lead to app rejection(!) ):

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
  <true/>
</dict>
```

Guess this might solve your problem. :)